# converting a number into text as it is

Tags: r, character

When converting a number to character how can I avoid this

```
> as.character(2146000000)
[1] "2.146e+09"
```

and get this?

```
 "2146000000"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to use `sprintf` and change punctually the format:

```
  sprintf("%.0f", 2.146e+09)
  "2146000000"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
as.character(2146000000)
#[1] "2.146e+09"
options(scipen=1)
as.character(2146000000)
#[1] "2146000000"
```

Comment: why it "you can accept an answer in 9 minutes"??

Comment: @Michele I have no idea actually.

Comment: @Michele, there's a 15 minute gap that is imposed.